# Expressjs app.locals in {{#each ...}} not accessible

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, locals

Hello i have something very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{adminUrl}}/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{adminUrl}}/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{adminUrl}}/assets/js/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{adminUrl}}/assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="padding: 20px; background: #fafafa; border-bottom: solid 1px #eee">
    <a href="{{adminUrl}}/users/" class="btn">users list/no paging</a>
    <a href="{{adminUrl}}/create/" class="btn">create new user</a>
</div>

    <h1>List data:</h1>

    <ol>
        {{#each data}}
            <li>
                <div><a href="{{adminUrl}}/details/{{id}}"><b>{{username}} - {{id}}</b></a></div>
                {{email}}
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ol>


</body>
</html>
```

This is an expressjs view that uses handlebars. 'adminUrl' is in app.locals.

```
app.locals({
    adminUrl: _config.rootUrl
});
```

In the css, js and a href links outside the {{#each works just fine, but in the {{#each... does not. How can i fix it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `{{../adminUrl}}` within your `{{#each}}` block as I believe handlebars will change the context to be the current member of `data` and thus you need `..` to access the parent context.